# How to use Kotlin Singleton class in Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, design-patterns, singleton

I've both Kotlin and Java files in my project. I converted a Java Singleton class in Kotlin using `object MySingletonClass`. But still this is being used by many java classes so added the fun like this to use in Java

```
 @JvmStatic
    fun getInstance(): MySingletonClass{
       return this@MySingletonClass
    }
```

but when I compile the project get below error in all Java files
`Cannot access class 'MySingletonClass'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`

The main question is how I could use Kotlin Object in Java.

Comment: Need to see more context of your code. It doesn’t make sense that the function has a context parameter when it doesn’t use it. And if your singleton needs a Context, then it doesn’t make sense to use an `object` that passes itself (`this`) as the singleton.

Comment: Correct I don't need the context, I just removed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to write any special function to use a Kotlin singleton object in Java. You can use the INSTANCE field, which the Kotlin compiler creates for you:

```
// In Java:
MySingletonClass obj = MySingletonClass.INSTANCE;
```

However, you said in your question that Java throws an error saying it cannot access the class MySingletonClass. That's a separate issue. Check that you're using the right package name in your import statement.

Comment: btw if anyone knows where it is stated officially at the Kotlin website that there is this INSTANCE field, could you let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: It's in some example code [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods) but I think they've neglected to explicitly state how to use it.